# What would be the symfony way of handling assigning a global value to multiple form fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have an application that allows people to create reports that contain widgets. These widgets  have their options set using their own form types. What im looking to do is allow the user to save a report as a template. The issue i have is that some of the options in the widgets are specific to a particular user/client so those options will need to be defined when the report is created from that template.

My question is how do I allow the user to define some of the options and leave the others to be defined when the report is created from the template.

Follow up question, how would I allow the user to define a "global" variable? For instance widget 1, 2 and 3 are all of the same Form Type and have and option that will be the same for all of them IE a start_time field. Then when the report is created it would look for all "global" options and allow the user to define a value for those then populate that throughout all the places that it was used.

EX: Lets say that I have 2 widget types,

```
class WidgetTypeOne extends AbstractType

...

    $builder->add('start_date', 'date')
    ->add('end_date', 'date');
```

And the other

```
 class WidgetTypeTwo extends AbstractType

 ...

 $builder->add('some_option','text);
```

Now lets say that the user has a report that has 4 of the WidgetTypeOne's and 2 of the WidgetTypeTwo's. I want to let the user see all of the options for them and say that for 3 of the 4 WidgetTypeOne's the "start_date" will be the same. so that when a report is created using this template the user is prompted to enter a "start_date" and that will be used to populate the data for those 3 widgets.

**Answers that lead to a solution will be rewarded with 300 rep once bounty is able to be added**

**UPDATE**

Would it be possible to create a new field type that would act similar to how the date field type works with multiple select boxes only one of the fields be the original field type and the other be a select for available "global variables"?

Something that would result in something like:

```
 <select name="form_name[field][use_options]">
     <option value="use_static">Use Static Value</option>
     <option value="define_on_create">Define When Created</option>
     <option value="add_global">Add New Global</option>
     ...The rest would be dynamically added by javascript
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="form_name[field][static_value]" />
```

This way i could parse the form and know where to use a global or a static value.

Answer (score 0):

A good way for the forms would probably be to auto-populate them from the template in your controller then use queries in your types to populate specific user/client  defined values.

For the global variable your paragraph confused me a bit. I am going to assume that what you want is for example to let a user define a start date which will then be auto completed in all report he creates. I would go with the usual database storage either with an array type field or a whole new entity (if you want different global variables per template).

Anyhow the doc is a really good place to start and worth a read if you haven't already been through it.

Comment: I have read through the doc, and have been working with symfony for the last 3 years. I likely didnt explain what im trying to do very well. I will update my question with a better explanation.